# Pushing a stuct into an array

Tags: arrays, struct

What i am attempting to do is elementary, adding a struct to a storage array.  But for some reason I am getting the following error

`TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (struct KYC.Fraud storage ref) returns (uint256))`

```
contract KYC {
    struct Fraud {
         address bank;
         bytes32 accountNumber;
         bytes32 routingNumber;
         uint256 amount;
         uint256 timestamp;
    }

    Fraud[] frauds; 

    function reportFraud (address bank, bytes32 accountNumber, bytes32 routingNumber, uint256 amount) external returns(uint256 fraudID) {
        Fraud memory fraud = Fraud(bank, accountNumber, routingNumber, amount, now);
        frauds.push[fraud];
        return frauds.length - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` is a function. You're using brackets as if it's an array where you lookup the index of a struct, which is what's causing your error. Just change `push[fraud]` to `push(fraud)`.